# Inspecting and reparing third generation (1996-2000) Dodge Caravan heater mode door

Tags: dodge, chrysler, heater

How can I inspect or repair the Dodge Caravan heater "mode door"?  How much must be removed beyond the glove box?

The mode door directs air to defrost or the heater vents, and it is controlled by an electronic switch on the dash. In my case it works inconsistently, making a clicking noise and ending up in the wrong position as often as not.  This makes driving the vehicle in certain weather hazardous, as the windshield fogs up uncontrollably.

I'm aware of "Heater Treater", a third party maker of replacement parts for blend doors, but they don't do mode doors as of this writing.

(The same fix should also apply to Plymouth Voyager, Chrysler Voyager, Chrysler Town & Country, Chrysler Grand Voyager, Lancia Voyager, and Volkswagen Routan)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a picture for you but to no avail.

The best thing that I can recommend is have someone turn the mode switch back and forth while you crawl around under the dash and listen for which motor is making noise. This will be external to the heater box.

Once you locate the mode control motor, remove it. The motor will have a male shaft sticking out that matches the female end of the mode door in the heater box. Inspect the female side of the mode door. Look for any cracks or plain missing chunks. If it looks ok, using a screwdriver gently rotate the door back and forth. It should turn smoothly.

While the motor is out, leave it plugged in and have that same person move the mode switch back and forth. Watch the male part sticking out for how it rotates. If you hear clicking or it does not move smoothly then the motor is the problem.